# Google maps works locally, on production it's not centered and positions are wrong

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm experiencing a peculiar problem using google maps. 
I've set up a "search nearest place" feature, using a list of shops (with latitude and longitude) saved in my DB. When user posts it's address I geocode it, mark it on the map as a green icon, and the I use the Haversine formula to fetch the 10 nearest location according to the inputted lat and long.

I then display all the locations in an html table, and put the relative markers on my google map, with a proper infowindow.

Everything works fine locally, but when I uploaded on the production server everything works but the map: my table is populated, distance is correctly calcolated, the source code (see below) shows all variables have been correctly interpreted, but the map starts completely zoomed in, centered somewhere in the pacific (insted of Italy), so zoomed in that I need to roll the mouswheel *a lot* before seeing something.

The marker are then showing on the ALMOST correct position - apart from the green one, which is absent. When I click on a marker, moreover, the infowindow starts 30 or 40 pixels from the left of the marker, instead of right above it as it happens locally.

I get no error in the console, the generated source code is exaclty the same between local and production version, and yet I experience this strange behaviour.

I've no idea on what might be happening, I tried searching google but I can't find something similar. If that's worth, the production server is a Linux Machine, php 5.3.2, and is on a "third level" denoting the linux machine, i.e. the url looks like http://lnx.mydomain.com/.

Anyone knows what might be happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[myapikey]&sensor=false&language=it"></script>    
<script>
var locations = [
      ['location1', 45.4592775, 9.1599699, ' PIAZZA VESUVIO 14, 20144'],
      ['location2', 45.4534901, 9.170425, ' P.LE STAZIONE PORTA GENOVA   5 / 3,']      
      ];
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();           
      var map;

      function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45,4510239, 9,1606903),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };                        

          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mappa'),mapOptions);

          var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(45,4510239, 9,1606903),
              map: map,
              title: 'user inserted address here'        
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'click', (function(startMarker){
              return function(){
                  infowindow.setContent('user inserted address here');
                  infowindow.open(map, startMarker);
              }
          })(startMarker));
          startMarker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');          

         var marker;

         for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,            
          });        

           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {                              
              return function() {             
                 infowindow.setContent('<div class="default-text">'+locations[i][0]+'<br /><br />'+locations[i][3]+'</div>');
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);                
              }           
           })(marker, i));
         } 

      }        

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);  
</script>
```

Comment: startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(45,4510239, 9,1606903)... are you shure?? Whats about (45.4510239, 9.1606903)

Comment: @steven Damn you're right, locally they're correctly written, on production they've the comma instead of a dot. Very good catch. Could it be a localization issue from the server?

Comment: hmmm, dont know? how did you uploaded your code?

Comment: A normal file upload through FileZilla. Those numbers are echoed in php, coming from a VARCHAR db field. Same exact code of the local development environment, anyway. Let me see when and where they're being changed...

Comment: the upper latlon coordinates are correct. But why do you use VARCHAR, i think float(10,6) is the best datatype for latlon. Did you do some number_format or something else before output?

Comment: I'm using VARCHAR because that's how I inherited the DB, you're right about the correct type. Anyway, the problem was the server locale, changing the float decimal separator. I solved setting it to en_US to keep the dot. Thank you for your help in spotting the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a localization problem... When var_dumped, a coordinate was correctly interpreted as `float`, but in my locale (`it_IT`) floats are written using the comma as separator.

So I just used

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US');
?>
```

and numbers were correctly printed with the dot as decimal point separator.  (I tried first with an ugly `str_replace()`, that would work too).

Kudos to @steven for spotting out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Damien, in Latin speaking countries in Europe (Spain, Italy, probably Romania) they use commas where we use periods, and vice versa:

1,000 in the USA,
1.000 in Latin speaking countries

1.25 in the USA,
1,25 in Latin Speaking countries

1,250,125.25 in the USA,
1.250.125,25 in Latin Speaking countries!

Strange, but true!

Comment: Yeah, I know that..I correctly used the dot (knowing Google uses it), server was localizing it to comma without me noticing, that was the problem. Btw, not only "Latin countries" use comma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark, if that were the point

Comment: Ok, maybe that will help someone else, then...  I just learned that in Spanish class in college.  I didn't want to assume they used commas in other Western countries, or Eastern countries (knowing nothing about them).